# Python: can I modify the log contents before logging into a file?

Tags: python, logging

Is there a way to mask the 'SECRET' information in the log with 'xxxxxxx' without changing the last line of code in below.

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(name)s:%(message)s')
file_handler = logging.FileHandler('sample.log')
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)

logger.info("Information contains SECRET stuff.")
```

If I run above code, I will get below log content:
2019-08-21 09:47:12,845:**main**:Information contains SECRET stuff.

Without changing the last line of code: logger.info("Information contains SECRET stuff"), is there a way to generate expected log as below:
2019-08-21 09:47:12,845:**main**:Information contains xxxxxxxx stuff.

Comment: There are several methods for modifying the log message in the [logging cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/logging-cookbook.html#context-info).

Comment: There are many ways to modify logs, e.g. when you want to add context information or change formatting, but to avoid logging sensitive data, it is best to never send sensitive data to `logger.info`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could inherit from the 'logging.Logger' class and provide your own 'info' method. Note the addition of the 'setLoggerClass' call to switch to the custom class.

```
import logging

class secretLogger(logging.Logger):

    def __init__(self,name,level=logging.NOTSET):
        super(secretLogger,self).__init__(name,level)

    def info(self,msg,*args,**kwargs):
        secretMsg = msg.replace('SECRET','xxxxxxxx')
        super(secretLogger,self).info(secretMsg,*args,**kwargs)

logging.setLoggerClass(secretLogger)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(name)s:%(message)s')
file_handler = logging.FileHandler('sample.log')
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)

logger.info("Information contains SECRET stuff.")
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to define a custom `LoggingAdapter` class whose `process` method modifies the incoming message. This follows the recipe from [the logging cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/logging-cookbook.html#context-info).

```
class StripSecret(logging.LoggerAdapter):
    def process(self, msg, kwargs):
        return msg.replace("SECRET", "XXXXXX"), kwargs

logger = logging.getLogger(...)
adapter = StripSecret(logger, {})
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not sure this is officially supported, log record contents can be manipulated inside a *filter* function. The following works for me:

```
def stripper_filter(record: logging.LogRecord) -> bool:
    record.msg = record.msg.replace("SECRET", "XXXXXX")
    return True

logger = logging.getLogger(...)
logger.addFilter(stripper_filter)
```

The advantage of this solution is that it can be hooked into already existing logger objects. The disadvantage is that some parts like `record.args` can't be modified.